# Why does XAMPP and MYSQL service can't run simultaneously

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
2024-03-24  8:48:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-03-24  8:48:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-03-24  8:48:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240324  8:48:52
2024-03-24  8:48:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-03-24  8:48:52 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

2024-03-24  8:48:52 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2024-03-24  8:48:52 0 [ERROR] Aborting
`your text``
```

I am expecting for the XAMPP to run just fine while the MYSQL service is running, maybe a problem to the port?`

Comment: the error message is clear, you have another mysql mariadb server on that machine running, set one server to port 3307 in the my.cnf file and both will run. or uninstall one of them

Comment: ...or you can probably NOT start the MySQL in XAMPP, and the other local instance will be found by phpMyAdmin. I've been able to use it that way at least, unless there's some version dependency. Of course, you can also configure 2 different ports as the previous comment suggested.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is a collection of services, the 'M' in the name stands for MySQL, and yes, the problem is the port: Only one server can listen on a network port at the time.

So, if you want to run another instance of MySQL/MariaDB, you need to either:

- Disable and terminate the MySQL installed by XAMPP, and then run the other instance, or
- Change the listing port on either instance of MySQL/MariaDB, which is by default 3306. Or you can configure MySQL/MariaDB to listen on a [Unix socket](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-connection-socket.html) (Named pipes on Windows).

Comment: Mysql default port is 3306

Comment: Ooops :-) thnks